# Add automation support to MFC DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, automation

Is there a way to add automation to an existing MFC dll?

I know I can create a new project and select Automation during the wizard, but I already have a dll with ATL support which exposes a number of COM objects so I'd rather update that than have to recreated it.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think so. I think it changes the DLL base class and some of the calls / structures in the init function. I'd create trivial new MFC DLLs with and without automation and diff them, and it may well be easier to add your files into a new project and merge in the automation init changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Article [Adding automation to MFC applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/mfc_autom.aspx) should help you.